# Storing strings from a text file/scanner. Array or built-in?

Tags: java, arrays

This code snippet is to to read a text file, turn the lines into objects through a different public (non changeable) class(externalClass).

The external class does nothing but turn strings (lines from the .txt through nextLine) into objects, and is fully functional. The scanner(scanner3) is assigned to the text file.

```
        while (scanner3.hasNext()) {
               externalClass convertedlines = new externalClass(scanner3.nextLine());
```

I'm not new to programming, but as I'm new to java, I do not know if this requires me to create an array, or if the returned objects are sorted in some other way. i.e is the "importedlines" getting overwritten with each run of the loop(and I need to introduce an array into the loop), or are the objects stored in some way?

The question may seem strange, but with the program I am making it would be harder (but definitely not impossible) if I used an array.

Any help would be appreciated.

As requested, externalClass:

```
public class exernalClass {
    private String line;

    externalClass(String inLine){   
        line = inLine;
    }

    public String giveLine() {
        return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Scanner reads a single line and returns as a String. 
It is totally upto you how you want to handle it. 
Hope it helps. 
ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Yes, but the strings are returned as objects through externalClass.

Do you mean that I should put the objects into an array?

Comment: May we see `externalClass`? Does `externalClass` have its own methods of storing data? If yes then your approach works, if no then you will need an array to store the scanner's input.

Comment: YOu are just replacing your object convertedLines for each line from your text file? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, andrew. That is correct. I consider my question answere now. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the `convertedlines` will be overwritten in every run of the loop.

Depending on what you want to do with the lines afterwards and if you know how big the files you read are some implementation of `Collection` (like an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`) may be a better fit than an array.

Comment: Can ->objects<- with string values be stores without information loss in a 'normal' array?